# ContentDialog delay after OK clicked

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

I have a helper method that shows an ContentDialog with an input box that accepts string data.  My issue is that it takes about 1 second after OK is clicked before the caller gets the string back (and it's very noticeable).  I theorized that maybe it was the dialog fading out default animation/transition to end before the dialog returned.

In the code below, there's about a 1 second delay between when OK is clicked on the dialog and when the "return textBox.Text" fires.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Shows an simple input box to get a string value in return.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="title">The title to show at the top of the dialog.</param>
    /// <param name="message">The message shown directly above the input box.</param>
    /// <param name="defaultValue">A value to prepopulate in the input box if any.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static async Task<string> ShowInput(string message, string defaultValue, string title)
    {
        var dialog = new ContentDialog
        {
            Title = title
        };

        var panel = new StackPanel();
        panel.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = message, TextWrapping = Windows.UI.Xaml.TextWrapping.Wrap });

        var textBox = new TextBox();
        textBox.Text = defaultValue;
        textBox.SelectAll();

        textBox.KeyUp += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
            {
                dialog.Hide();
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        };

        panel.Children.Add(textBox);

        dialog.Content = panel;
        dialog.PrimaryButtonText = "OK";            
        await dialog.ShowAsync();

        return textBox.Text;
    }
```

My questions are:

1. Am I missing something I should be setting or is this delay after clicking OK on the ContentDialog out the out of the box behavior?
2. If it is caused by a transition can I disable it?
3. Is there anyway I can speed up the time between when OK is clicked and the await returns?

I am running against 1809 Build 17763.379.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I tried reproducing the issue and I didn't notice any noticeable lag. Most probably this will vary based on the device, the app is running on.. did you try setting your solution config to release and running the application without debugging ?

Comment: Good idea.  Took a hot second to compile in release mode.  I still see the delay.  I might not have noticed it except the result moves a cursor on the screen and I had a thought string that went like "Hey, why didn't it move?  Oh, there it went."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Pratyay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7325217/pratyay) mentioned in his comment, the amount of time will vary by device.

But as far as the `await` keyword goes, I believe what you are experiencing is intended behavior.

> The await operator is applied to a task in an asynchronous method to insert a suspension point in the execution of the method until the awaited task completes. The task represents ongoing work.
>
> [Source @ Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await)

This means that your `ShowInput` function will return its `Task<string>` object as soon as it reaches the `await` keyword. Then after `dialog.ShowAsync();` returns it will continue the `ShowInput` function asynchronously and place the results into the Task object for you to retrieve.

So although your `ShowInput` function should return almost immediately. You will notice a delay between `dialog.ShowAsync();` and `return textBox.Text;`.

The other thing to keep in mind is that when a window closes, there is usually a bit of processing (disposing of resources, etc.) before the window loop finishes. The way your code is written, you will have to wait until all of that finishes before you get your result.

> Is there anyway I can speed up the time between when OK is clicked and the await returns?

I figure the quickest way to get your response back is to not await the ContentDialog, but rather await a signal that occurs right when the content is available.

```
public static Task<string> ShowInput(string message, string defaultValue, string title)
{
    var dialog = new ContentDialog { Title = title };

    var panel = new StackPanel();
    panel.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = message, TextWrapping = Windows.UI.Xaml.TextWrapping.Wrap });

    var textBox = new TextBox() { Text = defaultValue };
    textBox.SelectAll();

    var signal = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    textBox.KeyUp += (o, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
        {
            dialog.Hide();
            signal.SetResult(textBox.Text);
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    };
    dialog.PrimaryButtonClick += (o, e) => 
    {
        dialog.Hide();
        signal.SetResult(textBox.Text);
    };

    panel.Children.Add(textBox);

    dialog.Content = panel;
    dialog.PrimaryButtonText = "OK";            
    dialog.ShowAsync();

    return signal.Task;
}
```

Edit: Doing it this way no longer needs the extra await, as the Task being created has the final result in it.

Comment: To build off of that, is there a different way to use the ContentDialog than how I am using it?

Comment: My apologies, I seem to have forgotten question 3.

Comment: That was an incredibly clever addition.  It has the intended result of working instantly.  The only thing I had to add was an additional block to handle the primary button click in the same way you updated the Enter key.  Thank you again.

Comment: dialog.PrimaryButtonClick += (o, e) =>
    {
        dialog.Hide();                
        signal.SetResult(textBox.Text);
    };

Answer (score 2):

The following solution is not really a performance fix, since there is nothing wrong with the code you have posted.
The basic idea is - since this process takes a while based on the device you can just show a spinner / loading screen just before calling your `ShowInput()` method and hiding it after you are done using the value/text that is returned by the `ShowInput()`.

For example you can try something like this :

```
showLoader();
string x = await ShowInput("message","","title");
...
//some more code 
...
hideLoader();
```

Where showLoader/hideLoader will *show* or *hide* a lightweight loader screen something like this :

[image]

This will make sure user waits until the code has completed execution. (This might be overkill if you are doing something very trivial with the text input)